# JMS/MDB rollback

Tags: jms, rollback, message-driven-bean

We have a application, which reads of JMS and does some database transactions, all as part of one XA transaction..
If we find the message has some problems, we want to rollback the database,
but we don’t want the rollback off JMS to have us read the message again(we don't want the MDB to trigger the entire process one more if rollback was previously initiated).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be sure I understand you correctly: you have a transactional message-driven bean that performs some actions on database. You still want the MDB to be a part of XA transaction, but you don't want the database actions to influence the state of the transaction in which the MDB takes part in.

That being said, there are two solutions:

1. **If the MDB runs within a container-managed transaction**, wrap all the database actions into an EJB with `@REQUIRES_NEW` annotation — unless they're already all run in such transactional context.
2. **If your MDB is bean-managed**, the message delivery is NOT a part of transaction, so it will not be redelivered, no matter what — section 5.4.12 of *EJB Core Contracts and Requirements*:

   > When a message-driven bean using bean-managed transaction demarcation uses the javax.transaction.
   > UserTransaction interface to demarcate transactions, the message receipt that causes
   > the bean to be invoked is not part of the transaction.